# How do I use Grep to find a phrase that ends with a regex expression?

Tags: regex, grep, bbedit

I have a large text file that I am trying to separate into a CSV. Right now there are no line breaks, but each line that I want to separate will end with the regular expression **url is \S+**.

I am using bbedit to find and hopefully extract the lines. I originally tried putting a line break after it found that regex, but if I put **url is \S+\n** into the replace section it is taken literally and my url is gone.
Some expressions I've tried:

```
\burl is \S+
\b.*url is \S+ 
$url is \S+ 
.*$url is \S+ 
url is \S+ $
url is \S+\$
```

The syntax of each line is

```
<message>, post has <#> likes, profile is <name>, url is <characters>
```

So an example of the document is:

```
message 1 here, post has 37 likes, profile is name1, url is 8gjEobL1U4 message 2, some messages have commas in them, post has 182 likes, profile is name2, url is 89PI4JOscv here is another message, post has 105 likes, profile is someoneelse, url is 89baAOzDLj
```

Comment: I've never used sed before, but trying that just gives me the file in my terminal and doesn't appear to have any linebreaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -oP '.*? url is [^ ]+ *' file
```

Output:

```
message 1 here, post has 37 likes, profile is name1, url is 8gjEobL1U4 
message 2, some messages have commas in them, post has 182 likes, profile is name2, url is 89PI4JOscv 
here is another message, post has 105 likes, profile is someoneelse, url is 89baAOzDLj
```

Comment: That line didn't work in my terminal, but I used

    .*? url is [^ ]+ *

in bbedit and was able to extract the lines. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ I was able to use:

- Find what: `url is.+?` <- there is a space after the question mark
- Replace with: `$0\n`

I am assuming that you wish to split after the actual URL and not after the word "url"

[image]

Comment: In BBEdit, you would use a capture group and a backreference, so put the regex for the match you want to find in parenthesis, and then replace with \1\n (that is, \1=the contents of the matched string, and \n=your newline).

Comment: @Kerri BBEdit does not support \0? \0 should contain the entire matched result.

Comment: Oh sure! You can use \0 to match the entire matched result -- my point was that the $ wouldn't work, you need to use a slash.